# I am getting an error using pandas and matplot during plotting a graph

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

when I was trying to plot the graph using that code I get an error
What should I do?

link of jupyter notebook
[click me to get code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZwyB_G_yoFfuYD0fuh3xYpkqcXH0OdTC?authuser=1#scrollTo=UEJpa9m1S-GJ)

please check and do some correction

Comment: Please embed the code here in your post. Also, your Google Colab Notebook can not be accessed. I guess the correct link is `https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZwyB_G_yoFfuYD0fuh3xYpkqcXH0OdTC#scrollTo=UEJpa9m1S-GJ`? However, no error  is thrown. Please elaborate in your post.

Comment: After putting my question here my code works. I think stack overflow have magical power

Comment: notebook link----> 
        
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZwyB_G_yoFfuYD0fuh3xYpkqcXH0OdTC?usp=sharing